# Database space vs. rails/script processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

This may be a dumb/basic question, but I have a model `Program` with a business type of either "Work", "School", "Church", etc. Right now, it stores these in the database as chars "w","s","c", etc. However, if I do that, I have to run a `switch` (`case` in rails) to get the real name. I do these with a few other attributes.

Is it better to just store the exact value in the database instead of running this `case` statement? I guess its a question of saving database space over the time it takes to process the name (and I guess there is also an issue of code readability).

**EDIT**

I should clarify, these things only have 4 immutable values. There is an outside chance I may have to add one or two later, but it does not seem to make sense to create a new resource as there is really no CRUD actions done on these attributes.

**EDIT**

Program.rb

```
attr_accessible :org_type

validates :org_type, :presence => true.
                     :inclusion => %w[any c s c] # And have a case later
             #OR     :inclusion -> $w[Any Corporation School Church]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are likely to add more later just make it a resource. It gives you more advantages then disadvantages.

If you did this for performance reasons: First make it working with the resource. Then fix the performance. In this case it looks like premature optimisation. There is no need to not use a Resource here.

Also you expect already that values are being added so that makes the case quite clear.

Though, if you give more info, there might be even better solutions. It depends on which fields you need for each type.

Comment: This is my first rails app, so I am still learning. I didn't make it a resource because I am 100% positive I won't need that data anywhere else except here. I also know that I won't need anything except the name. I can search fine with `Program.where("org_type = ?",org_type).` So I thought a resource would be overkill. Is it really never overkill?

Comment: In my experience it takes more work to not use it. So only use it when performance is needed. It disables you from doing relations, more information adding. Soft-delete behaviours etcetera. So, yes I would just use a resource.

Comment: Would I not bother with controllers/views? Only admins would change it, and I see no reason for them to do so. I am positive those 4 options will not be deleted or edited. Or do I need to create all those (that was the work I was trying to avoid). Additionally, would a program belong_to an org_type, and an org_type has many programs?

Comment: Just create the model, no controllers or views if you don't need them. Add the 4 records automatically in there, maybe with your migrations for example